# Modifying state from another reducer in react

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm pretty new in react so this might be a silly question.

I'm working on an app that manage rss feeds, so the structure of my entire app is similar to this one

```
<div className="App">
    <Header />
    <Feeds />
</div>
```

both components have their own reducer and actions.

the problem appears when I'm trying to create a new feed (actually managed in the feeds reducer) from my header component. so I have to access to the state of the feedsReducer from my headerReducer.

I'm not sure how to proceed at this point.

should I access the feeds reducer from the header component? ( this also implies that the feedsReducer needs to know my header actions)

I'll add some code to make the problem clear

index.js

```
import feedsReducer from './components/Feeds/FeedsReducer';
import headerReducer from './components/Header/HeaderReducer';
const rootReducer = {
    feeds:feedsReducer,
    header: headerReducer
};
const store = createStore(combineReducers(rootReducer));
```

Header/Header.js

```
import { ADD_FEED } from './actions';

class Header extends Component {

    state = {
        feedUrl: ""
    };

    addFeed = () => {
        axios.post(
            '/feeds/add',
            {
                url: 'myNewRssFeed.com'
            })
            .then(feed => {
                //this is calling the HeaderReducer
                this.props.addFeed(feed.data);
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }

}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        addFeed: (feed) => dispatch({ type: ADD_FEED, payload: { feed } })
    };
};

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Header);
```

Header/actions.js

```
export const ADD_FEED = "ADD_FEED";
```

HeaderComponent/HeaderReducer.js

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
    const newState = {
        ...state
    }
    switch (action.type) {
        case storeActions.ADD_FEED:
            // at this point newState.feeds doesn't exist because it's part from the FeedsReducer
            newState.feeds = newState.feeds.push(action.payload.feed);
            break;
    }
    return newState;
}
```

Feeds/FeedsReducer.js

```
const initialState = {
    feeds: []
}
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    const newState = {
        ...state
    }
    switch (action.type) {
        //this action is commented because was recently moved to the headerComponent/actions.js
        /* case storeActions.ADD_FEED:
            newState.feeds = newState.feeds.push(action.payload.feed);
            break; */
        case storeActions.LOAD_FEEDS:
            newState.feeds = action.payload.feeds;
            break;
    }
    return newState;
}
```

Thanks in advice.

Comment: any reducer can handle any action type (as long as you keep the reducers as pure functions). not sure what you mean by __accessing__ another reducer. a [mcve] would help

Comment: by "accesing" I mean to add new feed (contained in the state of the feedsReducer) from my HeaderComponent (that has his own HeaderReducer)

Comment: technically, reducers are not bind to a specific component nor to a specific action type. without seeing an example of your data and exact use case its hard to advise on what to do. but in general, the `feedsReducer` can "listen" to action of type `HEADER_CHANGE` and interact with its payload.

Comment: I've added some code to the question. I know that the feedsReducer can listen to any action, but my question was if it was correct to call the feedsReducer from the HeaderComponent or I might be doing things wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really think you need to access reducer in any way. Reducer function will update store based on action it's listenning to. 
Here is an example:

```
import * as constants from 'constantpathhere';

export function feedReducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
   const { type, payload } = action;
   switch(type) {
      case constants.ADD_FEED: // listen to ADD_FEED action
         return {... state, data: payload };
      case constants.LOAD_FEEDS: // listen to LOAD_FEEDS
         return {...state, loading: true }
      ...
      default: 
         return state;

   }

}

export function headReducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
   const { type, payload } = action;
   switch(type) {
      case constants.ANY_ACTION: // listen to ADD_FEED action
         return {... state, data: payload };
      case constants.ANY_OTHER_ACTION_LOADING: // listen to LOAD_FEEDS
         return {...state, loading: true }
      ...
      default: 
         return state;

   }

}

//ACTIONS

export function loadFeeds() {
   return {
     type: constants.LOAD_FEEDS
   }
}

export function addFeed(payload) {
  return {
    type: constants.ADD_FEED,
    payload
  }
}

export function triggerAnyAction(payload) {
   return {
     type: constants.ANY_ACTION,
     payload
   }
}
```

These actions above may be dispatched from any component, be it `Header` or `Feeds`, only reducer(s) listening to that particular action will update the store.

Briefly, you only need to know which action to dispatch where and only reducer listing to that action will do whatever you instructed it to do

Comment: That was my previos approach, which I reied to modify for 2 reasons:
1) having a smaller and splitted actions and reducers.
2) in your approach I have to include both actions and reducers from the header component in the feed component. is this a good practice on React or.. it{s not that bad?